# How do I completely remove MenuLibre and reset all changes?

Tags: icons, menulibre

I wanted to know how I could remove MenuLibre and all changes I did with it. I only used it to change the icons of my applications, but I would now like to change all my icons to a new theme. When I do this, I can only change the icons, that I didn't change with MenuLibre. When I removed Menulibre using

```
sudo apt-get remove menulibre
```

it removed the programm, but the icons were still the same. I also tried reinstalling it and simply deleting the image I added for the application. But instead of showing the icon of my current icon-theme, now the icon for an unspecified program was shown. I also tried removing it with:

```
sudo apt-get purge menulibre
```

but it still would not work.

I hope there is a way to fix it, so that I don't always have to change every single icon when I like to change my icon-theme.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to the title. Accepting an answer is enough to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Menulibre does is copy the global `.desktop`file of an application, in `/usr/share/applications`, to `~/.local/share/applications`and edit the local one. The local one in `~/.local/share/applications` will then "overrule" the global one.

To revert, simply remove the corresponding `.desktop`file(s) in `~/.local/share/applications`, log out and back in. Dash and and the Unity Launcher will then use the global one in `/usr/share/applications` again.

`~/.local`is a hidden directory by default. Press (in your home directory) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make it visible.

#### Note

Editing global .desktop files is bad practice and won't help you in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!!! And no, I didnt realize I had an answer... I'm sorry. I thought, that I should get an email notification,  but I didnt. Gonna change the settings!